# grade avg calculator not returning correct answer

Tags: java, sum, average, addition

This is a program to calculate average grades and I cant figure out whats wrong with my code. It is returning the wrong answer.

Editing post to remove personal information.
:

```
/**
 * This program will calculate grade average of user input
 *  Date: 10/2/2015
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeAVG {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        avgGrade();
    }

    public static void avgGrade() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        double count = 0;
        double avgGrade = 0 ; 
        double grade;
        double total = 0; 
        System.out.println("Please input the grade");
        grade = keyboard.nextDouble();
        
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Please input the grade");           
            grade= keyboard.nextDouble();
            count = count + 1;
            if (grade < 0) break;
        
            total += grade;
            avgGrade = total/count;
        }
        
        System.out.println ("Sum is " +total);
        System.out.printf("The average of the  %.0f grades are %.2f " ,count ,avgGrade);
    }   
        
}
```

Output:

```
Please input the grade
100
Please input the grade
50
Please input the grade
-9
Sum is 50.0
The average of the  2 grades are 50.00
```

Sum should have been 150 and average 75.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take more care when writing a question - your presentation is all over the place, with code being formatted not as code, non-code being formatted as code, poor indentation and huge random bits of vertical whitespace. It's much easier to help people if they've written a good question to start with (and potential answerers will be much more likely to do so, too).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are reading a grade from the user before the while loop begins and you are ignoring this value afterwards.

You should remove those 2 lines and things will work as expected. I commented those lines in the snippet below to explicitely show you the problem.

```
public static void avgGrade() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double count = 0;
    double avgGrade = 0; 
    double grade;
    double total = 0; 
    // System.out.println("Please input the grade");
    // grade = keyboard.nextDouble();

    while(true){
        System.out.println("Please input the grade");           
        grade = keyboard.nextDouble();
        count = count + 1;
        if (grade < 0) break;

        total += grade;
        avgGrade = total/count;
    }

    System.out.println ("Sum is " +total);
    System.out.printf("The average of the  %.0f grades are %.2f " ,count ,avgGrade);
}
```

As a side note, you should always try to minimize the scope of each of your variable. Here, the `grade` variable is only use inside the `while` loop so you can directly write `double grade = keyboard.nextDouble();` and remove the declaration in the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding the `first` grade which you are accepting outside of the `while` loop to the `total`.
Also there is no point in incrementing the `count`, if the `grade` is not acceptable, so `increment` your `count` only after the `grade` check.

You can rewrite your while block something like

```
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please input the grade");
        grade = keyboard.nextDouble();
        if (grade < 0)
            break;

        count = count + 1;
        total += grade;


    }
    avgGrade = total / count;

    System.out.println("Sum is " + total);
    System.out.printf("The average of the  %.0f grades are %.2f ", count,
            avgGrade);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. Here is the final code

```
       /**
       * This program will calculate grade average of user input
       * 
       *    Date: 10/2/2015
       */
       import java.util.Scanner;
       public class GradeAVG {



public static void main(String[] args) {

    avgGrade()

}

public static void avgGrade() 
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    double count = 0;
    double avgGrade = 0 ; 
    double total = 0; 

    while(true){
            System.out.println("Please input the grade");           
         double grade= keyboard.nextDouble();

        if (grade < 0) break;
        count = count + 1;
         total += grade;

        avgGrade = total/count;



            }

        System.out.println ("Sum is " +total);
        System.out.printf("The average of the  %.0f grades are %.2f " ,count ,avgGrade);


}   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

- First, you do two assignments into grade before first reading from it (first one before the while loop and second inside the while loop), so the first input will be ignored entirely
- Second, you increment the count variable before checking whether to break the while loop, so you end up with count higher by 1 than should be
- Third, the average is computed inside the loop and will not be recalculated in the last (partial) iteration

The program will go like this:

- input: 100, count: 0, total: 0, avg: 0

  - input was ignored
- input: 50, count: 1, total: 50, avg: 50
- input: -9, count: 2, total: 50, avg: 50

  - loop exit, but incremented count before; did not recalculate avg